# Cant install Epson ET-3750 printer on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, printing, 19.10, epson

I downloaded the driver by searching for `ET-3750` [on the official homepage](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModuleFromResult) and choosed `ESC/P-R Driver 2 (generic driver)` in 64 bit, so the installation command is

```
dpkg -i Downloads/epson-inkjet-printer-escpr2_1.1.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
```

This worked and also the `lsb` dependency package is installed. When connecting the printer, it shows up in *printers*

[image]

but not on applications like the pdf viewer:

[image]

So I tried to remove the printer in the settings and add it. The printer got correctly detected. However, after the printer is added, I see a *searching for drivers* dialog. A few seconds later, I get a popup that the new printer couldn't be added:

[image]

When I now refresh the *printers* entry in the settings, there is no printer listed. In the past, the printer already worked on this machine. Since I havent printed very much in the last time, it's hard to say when this happened exactly.

I already tried removing and re-installing the driver without success.

Answer (score 0):

After re-opening the printer settings, I saw the printer from screenshot #2 in the question again and found a way to fix this problem: Click on *Additional printer settings* on the bottom of the printer settings screen. I was wondering that there were no printers listed, so I clicked the *add* button

[image]

Now expand *network printers* and select the epson printer with a IP address. On the right, choose *LPD/LPR waiting queue (passthru)*

[image]

After confirming, the *search for drivers* popup apears again. This time without errors. Click *apply* and when at least one page was printed, you'll notice that the second printer entry contains additionally meta-information like the ink state:

[image]

However, there is still a second entry for the same printer. I don't know why this is the case. It seems that Ubuntu shows the second entry as detected printer, that is just detected yet and not configured/installed for printing. To make it useable, we need to configure the printer like described there.

After refreshing the settings page, just the first one is listed and the second pseudo-printer was gone. This is a bit confusing. It could be some kind of bug, since the printer view was killed one time during the installation with a internal error. However, after figuring this out, it seems working well for now.